# Entity Framework many to many to same class and pivot table is not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a node that can have relations to another node. When it has one, it should be added to the references property of that other node.
E.g. if node A has node B in it's relations. Then node B has node A in it's references.

I define this using the following classes and fluent configuration:

```
public class Node
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Relations { get; set; }
    public List<Node> References { get; set; }
    public List<NodeRelation> RelationsPivot { get; set; }
    public List<NodeRelation> ReferencesPivot { get; set; }
}
```

and also in the pivot class

```
public class NodeRelation
{
    public int MainNodeId { get; set; }
    public Node MainNode { get; set; }
    public int SubNodeId { get; set; }
    public Node SubNode { get; set; }
    public string PropertyKey { get; set; }
}
```

and the following fluent configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
            .HasMany(n => n.Relations)
            .WithMany(n => n.References)
            .UsingEntity<NodeRelation>(
                l => l.HasOne<Node>(nr => nr.MainNode).WithMany(n => n.RelationsPivot).HasForeignKey(n => n.MainNodeId),
                r => r.HasOne<Node>(nr => nr.SubNode).WithMany(n => n.ReferencesPivot).HasForeignKey(n => n.SubNodeId),
                nr => nr.HasKey(f => new { f.MainNodeId, f.SubNodeId, f.PropertyKey })
            );
```

But I am not receiving the expected results. In a node that only has relations, the `RelationsPivot` property seems to be working properly, but the relations list is empty.

Also in this node it has nothing in the `ReferencesPivot` (which is correct), but has 1 node in the References property, which shouldn't be there.

I have tried several configurations but they don't work the way I want to. Can anyone help pointing out what I'm doing wrong in this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a many-to-many scenario, self-referencing or otherwise you can use either an inferred or explicit relationship. An inferred relationship is where the joining table/entity is not explicitly referenced:

```
public List<Node> Relations { get; set; }
```

In an explicit scenario you reference the relationship through the joining entity:

```
public List<NodeRelation> RelationsPivot { get; set; }
```

In either case you use one *or* the other, not both. In most cases an implicit relationship is easier to work with since A's will be interested in related B's not AB's. Where you would use the explicit joining entity would be cases where there are properties about the relationship in the joining entity that are significant, in your case the PropertyKey.

Your configuration however is set up for the implicit relationship so EF will seek to populate the Node.Relations / Node.References. The issue with the implicit model is that you won't be able to access other properties in the joining entity, so you should consider using the explicit joining entity relationship instead:

```
public class Node
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<NodeRelation> RelationsPivot { get; protected set; } = new List<NodeRelation>();
    public virtual ICollection<NodeRelation> ReferencesPivot { get; protected set; } = new List<NodeRelation>();
}
```

also in the NodeRelation it is adviseable to mark your FKs explicitly to avoid possible mismatches due to type:

```
public class NodeRelation
{
    public int MainNodeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MainNodeId))]
    public Node MainNode { get; set; }
    public int SubNodeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubNodeId))]
    public Node SubNode { get; set; }
    public string PropertyKey { get; set; }
}
```

then...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasMany(n => n.RelationsPivot)
    .WithOne(n => n.MainNode);
modelBuilder.Entity<NodeRelation>()
    .HasOne(n => n.SubNode)
    .WithMany(n => n.ReferencesPivot);
```

To expose Node.Relations and Node.References shortcuts you can use unmapped accessors:

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Node> Relations 
{ 
    get => RelationsPivot.Select(x => x.MainNode);
}

[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Node> References
{ 
    get => ReferencesPivot.Select(x => x.SubNode);
}
```

** Hopefully I have those the right way around... :)

Note that when building Linq queries, any querying against the relationships need to be done via the mapped Pivot navigation properties, you cannot access .Relations or .Referenes within the queries like you would be able to with the implicit mappings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It all makes sense now I know that I can't use both. The fluent syntax made it seem like it was possible :) 
Your solution works perfectly, some queries are a bit more complex now because I always have to navigate through the pivot, but now it works the way I want to which is great!